# AllowAnonymous Attribute overridden by IdentityServer Authentication .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

So I have a ASP.NET Core 1.1 WebApi secured with IdentityServer4. This works perfectly. However, I am trying to allow certain controllers to be accessed without a bearer token.

In the past I would just add [AllowAnonymous] to the Controller or the end-point, however it seems like IdentityServer's authentication takes precedence.

I keep getting:
"*IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.Infrastructure.NopAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No token found.*"

I also want to add that the error is received in the API's logging and not in IdentityServer's Logging

Initially I thought it could relate to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/143 . However, even when I downgraded to 1.0.3 of ASP.Net Core it still happens.

Anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: What web server are you using? I ask because I use Kestrel as the main web server, with an Apache Load Balancer in front. I had to ensure that the Apache servers would allow these paths without authentication, or the [AllowAnonymous] tag isn't effective.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the tip on Apache. I am just developing locally at this stage, which is Kestrel I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an error message - it just says that no token could be found - which is totally OK.

The request will flow anonymously to your controllers.

Comment: Thanks. My issue was routing. The info message " Failure message..." is very misleading. Hopefully this gets re-worded to be more indicative that it is only for info purposes.